# Get content of local-entry into Basic Authorization property

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using the esb as a mediator, to translate rest to soap basically. The soap I am invoking is secure, so I need a Authorization property. I have no problem using this service:

```
<resource methods="GET" uri-template="/getAllZones">
      <inSequence>
         <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="Authorization" expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode('user:password'))" scope="transport"></property>
         <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2"></property>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <zon:GetAllZones xmlns:zon="http://someUrl.xsd">
                  <Filter></Filter>
               </zon:GetAllZones>
            </format>
            <args></args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send>
            <endpoint key="myEndpoint"></endpoint>
         </send>
         <log level="full"></log>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"></property>
         <send></send>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
```

But I want to store the user and password as a local entry inside ESB. I have tried this:

```
<property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="Authorization" expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode(get-property('user'):get-property('password')))" scope="transport"></property>
```

But it is not working. Any Ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where did you set user and password?

Comment: In local-entries as a inline text, but I just want to store them, i dont care where if you have any better spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your values inside the registry. Then access them using get-property with scope registry.

For example, if you have some registry resource stored in `conf:/creds/user` and this has properties username and password, you can access those using:

`get-property('registry', 'conf:/creds/user@username')` and `get-property('registry', 'conf:/creds/user@password')`

As an example, in order to access properties setup as follows:
[image: Setting up Registry Resource Properties]

You would use something like:

```
  <inSequence>
     <log level="custom">
        <property name="Username" expression="get-property('registry', 'conf:/user@username')"/>
        <property name="Password" expression="get-property('registry', 'conf:/user@password')"/>
        <property name="Encoded" expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode(fn:concat(get-property('registry', 'conf:/user@username'), ':', get-property('registry', 'conf:/user@username'))))"/>
     </log>
     <respond/>
  </inSequence>
```

But you might want to consider encrypting the password. In which case you should use the secure vault inside the ESB. You can access something in a secure vault using alias `{wso2:vault-lookup('user')}`.

More details in https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Working+with+Passwords.

Comment: Thanks Abimaran, this may work but how can I store a value in the registry and retrive it?, I have tried but I am not able to retrive it correctly.

Comment: You can use the registry browser on the web console to add a registry resource. This is in https://localhost:9443/carbon/resources/resource.jsp?region=region3&item=resource_browser_menu&viewType=std&path=/_system/config Once you add the resource, click on it and you will then be taken to a UI where you can add properties to your resource. You can add the properties there and access them as above. For instance resource in /_system/config/user has property username=ravi, password=ravi, you can access those in xPath using something like get-property('registry', 'confi:/user@username').

Comment: I add 2 properties (user and password) in a resource call creds in de registry but wso2 does not let me set the get-property inside the property expression:

expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode(get-property('registry', 'config:/creds@user'):get-property('registry', 'config:/creds@password')))"

Comment: I don't think that expression string is what you want, please see my updated answer above for a sample.

Comment: Magnificent improved answer RaviU. It works as I expected. I will keep in  mind the vault-lookup for production enviroment. Thank you so much.